# Saving elements as variables in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm fairly new to Javascript and JQuery and I'm having a problem with what I thought would be straightforward.  I'm making a website composed of a single html page, a css stylesheet, and a Javascript file that retrieves data from somewhere and draws a network using d3.js.  I have an SVG element in my html that I need to access from the Javascript in order to change its attributes and draw in it.  I was originally creating the SVG element in my JQuery and saving the return value as a variable that I could use later.  However, this was kind of ugly because I had to remove and re-add the SVG every time I wanted to draw a new network.

So now I've added the SVG element right to the html, and gotten the layout to work nicely with the window resizing.  However, I can't seem to access it as easily from JQuery.  I tried something like this:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "XMidYMid")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
```

However, at `svg.attr(...)`, I get the error "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)')".

I also tried using `$("#svg")` in every place where I had used the `svg` variable.  However, this gave me the error "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#svg").append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")')".  Oddly, the function call before it,

```
$("#svg").attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "XMidYMid")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
```

... ran just fine.

I'm not sure if I'm confusing d3 syntax with JQuery and Javascript syntax, but it seems to me like a simple problem of saving an html element in a Javascript variable.  Is that a normal thing to do?  If so, what's the proper syntax?  If not, what should I be doing instead?

Comment: You cannot blindly mix D3 with jQuery. When you call `$("#svg").append("svg:defs")`, then you get back a jQuery object. jQuery objects don't have a `selectAll` method, that's D3. You always have to think about what kind of object you have and convert one to the other if you have to. The equivalent in D3 would be `d3.select('#svg').append('defs').selectAll('marker')` btw.

Comment: _"JQuery and Javascript syntax"_ - there is no difference in the _syntax_ of jQuery and JavaScript because jQuery _is_ JavaScript. That is, all jQuery code uses standard JS syntax. With or without jQuery you will get errors if you try to call methods on objects that don't have said methods defined, which is what happened when you tried to use `.attr()` (a method of jQuery objects) with `svg` (not a jQuery object).

Comment: @FelixKling - So how do I convert a jQuery object to a D3 object?  I can't seem to find any documentation on them or how they're different.

Comment: The `d3.select` method also accepts a DOM node instead of a selector: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select. So you could do `d3.select($jquery_obj.get(0))`. The other way round is a bit more complicated I think because D3 nests the DOM elements in a strange way. Best you set a breakpoint and inspect one of the D3 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working!  So there were two problems here... both because I wasn't aware that I was actually dealing with three kinds of objects.  I was then trying to call functions on those objects that weren't defined for them.

1) As Zenith and Sushanth pointed out, I was trying to call a jQuery function on a DOM element returned by `getElementById`.  To fix this, I could either use `$("#svg")` instead of a variable to call a jQuery function, or I could convert my DOM element variable into a jQuery object variable by doing `var $svg = ($svg);` and then referencing it as `$svg`.

2) As Felix Kling pointed out, I was calling the D3 function `selectAll` on a jQuery object. To fix this I had to replace `$("#svg").append("svg:defs").selectAll(...)` with  `d3.select('#svg').append('defs').selectAll(...)`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

That's because `attr()` is a [**jQuery method**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and you weren't calling it on a jQuery object the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

**.attr** is a jQuery method

In the first case the element is a  `DOM element` . So `attr will fail`

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
// svg is s DOM element
// no support for .attr here unless you convert this to jQuery object
//  $(svg)

$("#svg")
// jQuery object
```